# How to create macro to hide/show sheets automatically depending of a condition?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, show-hide, google-sheets-macros

I'm totally lost here!

My spreadsheet has one sheet " Product Master Record" with a table containing three columns: Product ID (numerical) | Product Description | Product Status.

Each product has its own sheet within the spreadsheet. 
The name of each sheet depends on the product status:

**- "Active" product:** sheet name = product name --> Sheet is visible

**- "Inactive" product:** sheet name = product ID --> Sheet is hidden

So I'm trying to write a macro which hide/shows sheets depending on the condition:

1. Product status (active/inactive)
2. Sheet name (if name contains text or not)

I don't need to write both conditions; only the easiest one to code.

Any ideas??
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you summarise the research that you've already done - we wouldn't want to double up on it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to distribute each data in product master record to each sheet based on product id, and the visibility depend on product status? Please a simple script as your attemption, so we can understand your flow

Comment: But for just an idea, you take records with id and status,  you check the id, for not blank text, you create new sheet just if the same sheet is not exist, rename it with id, then check the status, if inactive make it hidden, and repeat it until last record

Answer (score 0):

Here the sample for your purpose, ProdMaster, row 1 header [ProdId,Desc,Status], and rows afterward are data, and Status will be Inactive and Active:

```
function HideSheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ProdMaster');
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myValue = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + lrow).getValues();

  for (a=1; a<myValue.length+1; a++)
  {
    var target = myValue[a-1];
    var tsheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(target[0]);
    if(tsheet==null) spreadsheet.insertSheet(target[0]);
    if(target[2]=='Active') tsheet.showSheet();
    if(target[2]=='Inactive') tsheet.hideSheet();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As a way for solving your problem you could do the following, instead of using "Active" or "Inactive" as checkers for validating a boolean condition, in your "Product Master Record" you could set the status using the functions [TRUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093307?hl=en) and [FALSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093302?hl=en&ref_topic=3105413), in that way you could decouple hardcoded text from your code and avoid the trouble from someone misspelling the words "Active" or "Inactive".

```
function HideSheets() {
  
  // Get the active sheet and range of rows you want 
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mainSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Product Master Record');
  var rows = mainSheet.getRange("A2:C" + mainSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // Iterate over all rows 
  for(row in rows){
    // Get the sheets from their names and check if not null
    var secondarySheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(rows[row][0]);
    if(secondarySheet){
       if(rows[row][2]) secondarySheet.showSheet(); // show the sheet if value is true
       if(!rows[row][2]) secondarySheet.hideSheet(); // hide sheet if value is false
    }
  }
  
};
```

### Docs

I can see your new in this wonderful world. I will give you some docs to help you in your path of learning:

- [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

Finally I found help with a colleague and it works. This is the code in case someone finds useful:

```
function updateSheetFromIndex(index)
{
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameOfTheMenu);
    var cell = activeSheet.getRange(index, 5);
    var formula = cell.getFormula();
    var regExpr = /\#gid=([0-9]*)"/;
    var result = regExpr.exec(formula);
    var cellStatus = activeSheet.getRange(index, 4);

    Logger.log(index)
    if (result != null) {
       var gid = result[1];

       for each (var sheet in SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()) {
         if(sheet.getSheetId()==gid){
           if (cellStatus.getValue() == "Activo") {
             Logger.log("Activo---");
             sheet.showSheet();
           }

           if (cellStatus.getValue() == "Inactivo") {
             Logger.log("Inactivo---");
             sheet.hideSheet();
           }
           break;
         }
       }
    } else {
      Logger.log("+++ No pattern matches");
      Logger.log("Formula");
      Logger.log(formula);
    }

}
```